# Hide input field until certain dropdown value has been selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to keep a textfield in HTML hidden until a certain value of a drop-down-list has been selected. I'm extremely bad at javascript, and I've been searching around for a solution for quite some time.

This is what I could scrape together so far:

Javascript code:

```
function newCustomerType()
{
    var ddl = document.getElementById("customerType");
    var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;

    if (selectedValue == "new")
    {
        document.getElementById('newType').type = text;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('newType').type = hidden;
    }
}
```

HTML code:

```
<form id="newCustomer" name="newCustomer" method="post" action="">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="customerName"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Type:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select id="customerType" name="customerType">
                <option value="existing">existing type</option>
                <option value="new">new type:</option>
            </select>
            <input type="hidden" id="newType" name="newType"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Register"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

This does not seem to work. What is it that I'm doing wrong?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to do `type = "text"` as a string since text is `undefined`, same goes for `type = "hidden"`, you can also use `setAttribute` to change the type.

Comment: You'll need to call your function when the selected option changes. You might consider the [`onchange()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/onchange)` event listener. Do you really want it to be a hidden field (`type="hidden"`)? Or just hidden from view (`display:none`)?

Comment: showdev - just hidden from view until the option "new type" has been selected is good enough. Kyle - made the changes you suggested, but the textfield stays hidden regardless of the dropdown option that's chosen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check this out http://jsfiddle.net/2AALG/

Change the input type to 'text' and set the stylesheet display = none

```
 <input type="text" id="newType" name="newType" style="display:none"/>
```

And add a change handler in javascript, and use it to change the style

```
var ddl = document.getElementById("customerType");
ddl.onchange=newCustomerType;
function newCustomerType()
{   
    var ddl = document.getElementById("customerType");
    var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;


    if (selectedValue == "new")
    {   document.getElementById("newType").style.display = "block";
    }
    else
    {
       document.getElementById("newType").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: This was basically my answer, but a few suggestions: 1) in order to display it, set style.display to "", not "block".  2) `var selectedValue = ddl.value` also works, much simpler.  3) instead of setting the inline style in the html, just call the newCustomerType() function to initialize the input to hidden.